# How to protect array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have problem with my site. I have to make website using [this](https://github.com/tehsis/jfortune) and laravel.
So, using this jQuery plugin, i have to set "prices" as array.
And now, my problem, how can I protect this prices?
I want to do this "anti editing" by developer console, how?
Maybe can I "skip" javascript code? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's always a good practice to have a front-end and back-end validator.

Comment: what does `protect the prices` even mean? If you send data to browser ... anyone can access it

Answer (score 2):

You can completely lock up an *Object* by using [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) on it

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]; // [1, 2, 3]

Object.freeze(arr);
// can't modify
arr[1] = 100;
// can't delete
delete arr[1];
// can't add
arr[3] = 4;
// arr.push(5); // will `throw` a TypeError
// same as at freeze time
arr; // [1, 2, 3]
```

Freezing doesn't flow down nested objects, if you wish for any children to be frozen as well you will need to iterate over the properties of your object too.

---

Please note

1. Once frozen you cannot unfreeze your *Object*.
2. You should never assume any data coming from a client has not been tampered with. Always validate it server side.

Comment: the object is frozen.. but what about the reference?

Answer (score 0):

In order to truly prevent someone from changing the price, you'll need to add validation on the back end (PHP, in your case). You can add validation on the front end using Javascript, but a malicious user can easily modify the Javascript to avoid the validation.

Essentially, then, what you'd need in PHP is something like this:

```
if(<price sent from the client> !== <price I expect>)
    <disallow action>
```